# Is there any way to mass rename or import field names in Labels in Symbology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, labeling, symbology

I need to load an .avl that sets the symbology for me, but I also need to give the unique values their name, which is not what the Symbology->Category->Value Field uses, but another field in that layer (or in another, but that's just a join...) I do not know if there is a way to import other fields for labeling.

I am using 10.2.2 version of ArcMap.

[image: labelstochange]

I only want to change the labels, not one by one, but to change it to another field. The coloumn marked with the arrow should go like "a,b,c,d...".

Comment: I'm surprised that you've still got an AVL, I haven't seen one of them in a decade (10 years). What happens if you try to load? does it fail? is there an error message? Does it just not label the layer? Have you considered adding the field it's looking for and calculating the values to what you have got or alternately setting the alias of the field that you intend to use to match... perhaps the field alias will be picked up by the tool but there's no guarantee.

Comment: The .avl is working perfectly, and the fileds match the .avl. My problem is that the labeling is the name of the field automatically, however i want to label with another filed of that layer.
The Symbology created used field1 for the classification and goes like 1,2,3,4... and filed to contains the names like a,b,c,d...
I cant change the value filed because i need the exact simbols, but i also need to label them with field2.

Comment: You can import symbology from another layer and apply it to different field.  Properties-symbology-import.

Comment: Yes i can but then the field won't match anything as it will try to match 1,2,3,4 with a,b,c,d also still trying to label 1,2,3,4 so the imported symbology will leave me with my oroginal, and everything will be in "al otther values"

Comment: What @FelixIP is saying is a good idea, import it once and 'fix' it for only that one layer then save as ArcGis LYR file and use Import Symbology from Layer tool for the rest of your layers. Nice one Felix!

Comment: @Harkat if you want someone to hear you, place at before his/her name